# Why is ArcPy Describe Extent overshooting the extents?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, extents, arcgis-10.6

Why is `arcpy.Describe(file.shp).extent` overshooting the extent? Screenshot below. I have confirmed there are no tiny lines lingering out at the edges. I'm in UTM coordinates.

```
extent = arcpy.Describe(Lines.shp).extent
xmin = extent.XMin
xmax = extent.XMax
ymin = extent.YMin
ymax = extent.YMax

print xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax
```

[image]
Print output:

```
540375.245005 546724.102422 3814174.9483 3818495.05067
```

**EDIT:** I tried adding in a minimum bounding geometry, still same issue.

```
test_out = outpath + '\\' + 'temp_convexHull.shp'
arcpy.MinimumBoundingGeometry_management(Lines.shp, test_out, "CONVEX_HULL", "ALL", "", "")

extent = arcpy.Describe(test_out).extent
xmin = extent.XMin
xmax = extent.XMax
ymin = extent.YMin
ymax = extent.YMax

print xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your thinking is slightly wrong

```
xmin = extent.XMin
xmax = extent.XMax
ymin = extent.YMin
ymax = extent.YMax
```

gives you this and it is OK and what envelope means.

[image]